# Why does lubridate mdy() return an error in lapply()?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to understand why my `lubridate` `mdy()` function is returning an error in `lapply()` to convert dates in a `dplyr` pipeline. I have used `mdy()` on other data in a similar method but have yet to see this issue. I am relatively new to R but had been able to troubleshoot other issues until now. I am not very familiar with how to use `lapply()`.

My data is a large .csv of water quality data, which I'm subsetting to simply show the data in question.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
require(lubridate)

wq.all<-as.data.frame(read.csv('C:/WQdata.csv',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

test.wq<-wq.all[1:5,12:13]

class(test.wq)
[1] "data.frame"
mode(test.wq)
[1] "list"
str(test.wq)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ YearMonth : chr  "2019-07" "2019-06" "2019-05" "2019-04" ...
 $ SampleTime: chr  "07/09/2019 14:44" "06/10/2019 14:17" "05/22/2019 14:31" "04/08/2019 14:15" ...
```

In `str(test.wq)`, `SampleTime` is the data in question which I am trying to coerce from `chr` to `date`, or at least `num`.

First, I don't need the time values, so I used `dplyr` `mutate()` to create `SampleDate` with only the 10-character dates, and then was attempting to coerce using `mdy()`:

```
wq.date<-test.wq%>%
  mutate(SampleDate=str_sub(test.wq[[2]],start=0,end=10))%>%
  mdy(SampleDate)
```

But this returns an error:

```
Error in lapply(list(...), .num_to_date) : object 'SampleDate' not found
```

If I only use `mutate()` it all seems to work fine, and gives me the new `SampleDate` column I was looking for:

```
wq.date<-test.wq%>%
  mutate(SampleDate=str_sub(test.wq[[2]],start=0,end=10))

head(wq.date)

  YearMonth       SampleTime SampleDate
1   2019-07 07/09/2019 14:44 07/09/2019
2   2019-06 06/10/2019 14:17 06/10/2019
3   2019-05 05/22/2019 14:31 05/22/2019
4   2019-04 04/08/2019 14:15 04/08/2019
5   2019-03 03/13/2019 14:19 03/13/2019

str(wq.date)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ YearMonth : chr  "2019-07" "2019-06" "2019-05" "2019-04" ...
 $ SampleTime: chr  "07/09/2019 14:44" "06/10/2019 14:17" "05/22/2019 14:31" "04/08/2019 14:15" ...
 $ SampleDate: chr  "07/09/2019" "06/10/2019" "05/22/2019" "04/08/2019" ...
```

So it only seems to result in error once I attempt to coerce using `mdy()`, even though `SampleDate` clearly exists and I believe I was referencing it correctly. 
I have researched other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536111/why-are-my-csv-file-dates-not-parsing-via-mdy-lubridate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180051/apply-and-lubridate?noredirect=1&lq=1), but neither seem to get to quite this issue.

Thoughts? Many thanks!

Comment: You're calling `mdy` on a data frame instead of a vector. This is more or less a typo

Comment: I can see that your variables are `char`. Format them `as_date`. Something along `wq.date$SampleDate <- mdy(wq.date$SampleDate)` might help. So the `  `mdy(SampleDate)` will be meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to have it inside `mutate` or extract the column, otherwise, it is applying the function on the entire data.frame.  According to `?mdy`

> Transforms dates stored in character and numeric vectors to Date or POSIXct objects

So, if the input is not a `vector`, it won't work

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
test.wq%>%
   mutate(SampleDate=str_sub(SampleTime,start=0,end=10))%>%
   mutate(date = mdy(SampleDate))
```